# Wrap calls to methods of a Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to wrap a number of class methods in Python with the same wrapper.

Conceptually it would look something like this in the simplest scenario:

```
x = 0 # some arbitrary context

class Base(object):
    def a(self):
       print "a x: %s" % x

    def b(self):
       print "b x: %s" % x

 class MixinWithX(Base):
     """Wrap"""
     def a(self):
         global x
         x = 1
         super(MixinWithX, self).a()
         x = 0

     def b(self):
         global x
         x = 1
         super(MixinWithX, self).a()
         x = 0
```

Of course, when there are more methods than `a` and `b`, this becomes a mess. It seems like there ought to be something simpler. Obviously `x` could be modified in a decorator but one still ends up having a long list of garbage, which instead of the above looks like:

```
 from functools import wraps
 def withx(f):
     @wraps(f) # good practice
     def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
         global x
         x = 1
         f(*args, **kwargs)
         x = 0
     return wrapped

 class MixinWithX(Base):
     """Wrap"""
     @withx
     def a(self):
         super(MixinWithX, self).a()

     @withx
     def b(self):
         super(MixinWithX, self).b()
```

I thought about using `__getattr__` in the mixin, but of course since methods such as `a` and `b` are already defined this is never called.

I also thought about using `__getattribute__` but it returns the attribute, not wrapping the call. I suppose `__getattribute__` could return a closure (example below) but I am not sure how sound a design that is. Here is an example:

```
 class MixinWithX(Base):
    # a list of the methods of our parent class (Base) that are wrapped
    wrapped = ['a', 'b']

    # application of the wrapper around the methods specified
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
       original = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
       if name in wrapped:
          def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
              global x
              x = 1 # in this example, a context manager would be handy.
              ret = original(*args, **kwargs)
              x = 0
              return ret
          return wrapped
       return original
```

It has occurred to me that there may be something built into Python that may alleviate the need to manually reproduce every method of the parent class that is to be wrapped. Or maybe a closure in `__getattribute__` is the proper way to do this. I would be grateful for thoughts.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, but I think you are looking for decorators.

Comment: @Lattyware: Decorators do not assist. For clarity, I am looking to have a sub-class that defines as a list the methods on the parent class that are to have their contexts changed prior and subsequent to execution. The methods in turn would not need to be individually defined in the sub-class (and hence there would be no place for a decorator).

Comment: to wrap all methods see [How to wrap every method of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt, which allows for a more terse syntax...

```
x = 0 # some arbitrary context

# Define a simple function to return a wrapped class
def wrap_class(base, towrap):
    class ClassWrapper(base):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            original = base.__getattribute__(self, name)
            if name in towrap:
                def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    global x
                    x = 1
                    try:
                        return original(*args, **kwargs)
                    finally:
                        x = 0
                return func_wrapper
            return original
    return ClassWrapper


# Our existing base class
class Base(object):
    def a(self):
       print "a x: %s" % x

    def b(self):
       print "b x: %s" % x


# Create a wrapped class in one line, without needing to define a new class
# for each class you want to wrap.
Wrapped = wrap_class(Base, ('a',))

# Now use it
m = Wrapped()
m.a()
m.b()

# ...or do it in one line...
m = wrap_class(Base, ('a',))()
```

...which outputs...

```
a x: 1
b x: 0
```

Comment: I might add that this would have the advantage of working on class methods.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt True. The monkey-patching approach in the accepted answer seemed like overkill to me, although there might be a minor performance advantage. Either way, if you're manually specifying a subset of 'attributes' to wrap, then the `inspect` stuff is almost certainly unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Aya. I went with `__getattribute__` for what I was doing, but I accepted the above answer because it was neat - though on reflection your answer is likely more illuminating for those trying to figure out how this sort of thing works.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt No worries. It was an interesting challenge. I spent a bit of time looking at class decorators and metaclasses, then finally fell back to a very old-school approach, since I was focusing on making it easy to wrap a large number of existing (and possibly unchangeable) classes with a minimal amount of effort.

Comment: this fails when a child class calls `super().some_method()`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using decorators and [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html):

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def withx(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print "decorator"
        x = 1
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        x = 0
    return wrapped

class MyDecoratingBaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for member in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
            if member[0] in self.wrapped_methods:
                setattr(self, member[0], withx(member[1]))

class MyDecoratedSubClass(MyDecoratingBaseClass):
    wrapped_methods = ['a', 'b']
    def a(self):
        print 'a'

    def b(self):
        print 'b'

    def c(self):
        print 'c'   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_instance = MyDecoratedSubClass()
    my_instance.a()
    my_instance.b()
    my_instance.c()
```

Output:

```
decorator
a
decorator
b
c
```

Comment: If we're going to monkeypatch, why not just run `for method in wrapped_methods: setattr(self, method, withx(getattr(self, method)))`? No need for `inspect` at all.

Comment: I would caveat that this answer, unlike Aya's wrapper / `__getattribute__` solution(s), will not work for class methods since `__init__` shall not have been called and there is no instance to monkeypatch.

Comment: Aya's answer is a much better way of doing this - you should accept her answer instead, it's significantly cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

There are two general directions I can think of which are useful in your case.

One is using a *class decorator*.  Write a function which takes a class, and returns a class with the same set of methods, decorated (either by creating a new class by calling `type(...)`, or by changing the input class in place).

EDIT: (the actual wrapping/inspecting code I had in mind is similar to 
what @girasquid has in his answer, but connecting is done using decoration instead of mixin/inheritance, which I think is more flexible an robust.)

Which brings me to the second option, which is to use a *metaclass*, which may be cleaner (yet trickier if you're not used to working with metaclasses).  If you don't have access to the definition of the original class, or don't want to change the original definition, you can subclass the original class, setting the metaclass on the derived.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, and it's called a decorator. Google "python decorators" for lots of information.

The basic concept is that a decorator is a function which takes a function as a parameter, and returns a function:

```
def decorate_with_x(f)
    def inner(self):
         self.x = 1 #you must always use self to refer to member variables, even if you're not decorating
         f(self)
         self.x = 0
    return inner

class Foo(object):

     @decorate_with_x # @-syntax passes the function defined on next line
                      # to the function named s.t. it is equivalent to 
                      # foo_func = decorate_with_x(foo_func)
     def foo_func(self):
         pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. Decorators do not address the issue; please see the edit above.

Comment: To illustrate why I am trying to solve this the way I am, try writing the wrapper for functions `a` to `z`, then doing it for two to three other classes with entirely different method names. It's a disgusting amount of useless repetition. There has to be a better way.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt I see you have accepted an answer which proposes decorators as the solution.

Comment: Indeed, though the relevant bit was the inspection/monkeypatching. Decorators are in this case interchangeable with closures and context managers, though none of them in the absence of inspection/monkeypatching could constitute an actual solution to the question themselves.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt Decorators are always interchangeable with functions, because they are just functions. You'll note that everyone mentioned decorators, because that is what your question suggests you need.

Comment: Everyone also mentioned functions and classes.