# Wrapping all possible method calls of a class in a try/except block

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming, wrapper, metaclass, python-decorators

I'm trying to wrap all methods of an existing Class (not of my creation) into a try/except suite. It could be any Class, but I'll use the **pandas.DataFrame** class here as a practical example.

So if the invoked method succeeds, we simply move on. But if it should generate an exception, it is appended to a list for later inspection/discovery (although the below example just issues a print statement for simplicity).

*(Note that the kinds of data-related exceptions that can occur when a method on the instance is invoked, isn't yet known; and that's the reason for this exercise: discovery).*

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class) was quite helpful (particularly @martineau Python-3 answer), but I'm having trouble adapting it. Below, I expected the second call to the (wrapped) *info()* method to emit print output but, sadly, it doesn't.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools, types, pandas

def method_wrapper(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): #Note: args[0] points to 'self'.
        try:
            print('Calling: {}.{}()... '.format(args[0].__class__.__name__,
                                                method.__name__))
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            print('Exception: %r' % sys.exc_info()) # Something trivial.
            #<Actual code would append that exception info to a list>.
    return wrapper


class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, class_name, base_classes, classDict):
        newClassDict = {}
        for attributeName, attribute in classDict.items():
            if type(attribute) == types.FunctionType: # Replace it with a
                attribute = method_wrapper(attribute) # decorated version.
            newClassDict[attributeName] = attribute
        return type.__new__(mcs, class_name, base_classes, newClassDict)

class WrappedDataFrame2(MetaClass('WrappedDataFrame',
                                  (pandas.DataFrame, object,), {}),
                                  metaclass=type):
    pass

print('Unwrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():')
pandas.DataFrame().info()

print('\n\nWrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():')
WrappedDataFrame2().info()
print()
```

This outputs:

```
Unwrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Empty DataFrame

Wrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():   <-- Missing print statement after this line.
<class '__main__.WrappedDataFrame2'>
Index: 0 entries
Empty WrappedDataFrame2
```

In summary,...

```
>>> unwrapped_object.someMethod(...)
# Should be mirrored by ...

>>> wrapping_object.someMethod(...)
# Including signature, docstring, etc. (i.e. all attributes); except that it
# executes inside a try/except suite (so I can catch exceptions generically).
```

Comment: P.S. If I delay in my response to comments or answer, it may be because I'm trying the suggestion out or trying to understand it first. =:)

Answer (score 2):

long time no see. `;-)` In fact it's been such a long time you may no longer care, but in case you (or others) do...

Here's something I *think* will do what you want. I've never answered your question before now because I don't have `pandas` installed on my system. However, today I decided to see if there was a workaround for not having it and created a trivial dummy module to mock it (only as far as I needed). Here's the only thing in it:

`mockpandas.py`:

```
""" Fake pandas module. """

class DataFrame:
    def info(self):
        print('pandas.DataFrame.info() called')
        raise RuntimeError('Exception raised')
```

Below is code that seems to do what you need by implementing @Blckknght's suggestion of iterating through the MRO—but ignores the limitations noted in his answer that could arise from doing it that way). It ain't pretty, but as I said, it seems to work with at least the mocked `pandas` library I created.

```
import functools
import mockpandas as pandas  # mock the library
import sys
import traceback
import types

def method_wrapper(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): # Note: args[0] points to 'self'.
        try:
            print('Calling: {}.{}()... '.format(args[0].__class__.__name__,
                                                method.__name__))
            return method(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            print('An exception occurred in the wrapped method {}.{}()'.format(
                    args[0].__class__.__name__, method.__name__))
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            # (Actual code would append that exception info to a list)

    return wrapper

class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, class_name, base_classes, classDict):
        """ See if any of the base classes were created by with_metaclass() function. """
        marker = None
        for base in base_classes:
            if hasattr(base, '_marker'):
                marker = getattr(base, '_marker')  # remember class name of temp base class
                break  # quit looking

        if class_name == marker:  # temporary base class being created by with_metaclass()?
            return  type.__new__(meta, class_name, base_classes, classDict)

        # Temporarily create an unmodified version of class so it's MRO can be used below.
        TempClass = type.__new__(meta, 'TempClass', base_classes, classDict)

        newClassDict = {}
        for cls in TempClass.mro():
            for attributeName, attribute in cls.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(attribute, types.FunctionType):
                    # Convert it to a decorated version.
                    attribute = method_wrapper(attribute)
                    newClassDict[attributeName] = attribute

        return type.__new__(meta, class_name, base_classes, newClassDict)

def with_metaclass(meta, classname, bases):
    """ Create a class with the supplied bases and metaclass, that has been tagged with a
        special '_marker' attribute.
    """
    return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, {'_marker': classname})

class WrappedDataFrame2(
        with_metaclass(MetaClass, 'WrappedDataFrame', (pandas.DataFrame, object))):
    pass

print('Unwrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():')
try:
    pandas.DataFrame().info()
except RuntimeError:
    print('  RuntimeError exception was raised as expected')

print('\n\nWrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():')
WrappedDataFrame2().info()
```

Output:

```
Unwrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():
pandas.DataFrame.info() called
  RuntimeError exception was raised as expected


Wrapped pandas.DataFrame().info():
Calling: WrappedDataFrame2.info()...
pandas.DataFrame.info() called
An exception occurred in the wrapped method WrappedDataFrame2.info()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "mockpandas.py", line 9, in info
    raise RuntimeError('Exception raised')
RuntimeError: Exception raised
```

As the above illustrates, the `method_wrapper()` decoratored version *is* being used by methods of the wrapped class.

Answer (score 1):

Your metaclass only applies your decorator to the methods defined in classes that are instances of it. It doesn't decorate inherited methods, since they're not in the `classDict`.

I'm not sure there's a good way to make it work. You could try iterating through the MRO and wrapping all the inherited methods as well as your own, but I suspect you'd get into trouble if there were multiple levels of inheritance after you start using `MetaClass` (as each level will decorate the already decorated methods of the previous class).

Comment: is monkey patching directly pd.DataFrame one of the solutions?

Comment: Monkey patching could be an option. I wrote the author of Pandas to get his take, too (outside of StackOverflow). Maybe he has some thoughts, and I'll happily share that when I get in touch with him. Trying not to go too far off the beaten path, yet. =:)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Blckknght . Will pondering your answer more.

Comment: Hi @Blckknght. Thank you for the interesting MRO approach answer. Regarding the valid concern you mentioned ('multiple levels of inheritance), do you mean as a result of possibly sub-classing "MetaClass" and/or 'WrappedDataFrame2' in the future? Or some other side-effect? (Btw, 'MetaClass' here is for this one-time/exclusive private use). Thanks.