# Wrapping only the 'most recent' implementation of a method in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper

I've implemented automatic wrapping of a method as described in [how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class) in the following manner:

```py
from functools import wraps
from somewhere import State

def wrapper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        _instance.state = State.Running
        method(_instance, *args, **kwargs)
        _instance.state = State.Finished
    return wrapped

class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        newClassDict = {}
        for attributeName, attribute in classDict.items():
            if isinstance(attribute, FunctionType) and attributeName == 'run':
                # replace it with a wrapped version
                attribute = wrapper(attribute)
            newClassDict[attributeName] = attribute
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, newClassDict)

class AmazingClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State.Idle

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.state)  # State.Running
        do_something()
        # After returning: self.state == State.Finished
```

An issue arises when deriving from `AmazingClass` and overriding `run()`

```py
class EvenMoreAmazingClass(AmazingClass):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.state)  # State.Running
        super().run(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.state)  # State.Finished set by base-implementation of run (undesired) !!!!
        do_something_else()
        # self.state should only reach State.Finished after returning from here
```

The problem is that the base-implementation of `run()` already sets `self.state` to `State.Finished`.
I want to call the base-implementation of `run()` and also not have to do any trickery in any classes derived from `AmazingClass` to keep `self.state == State.Running`.

So the question arises, is there a way to detect and wrap only the outermost implementation of `run()`? (In this case `EvenMoreAmazingClass.run()`)

Comment: Could you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

In `MetaClass.__new__`, you should keep a copy of the non-wrapped method, name that copy `_run`.

Then when you call `super()`, you can use that copy instead of the wrapped `run`.

Full code:

```
from functools import wraps


class Wild:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return attr

State = Wild()

def do_something(*args):
    print('Doing something', *args)


def wrapper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        _instance.state = State.Running
        method(_instance, *args, **kwargs)
        _instance.state = State.Finished
    return wrapped


class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        newClassDict = {}
        for attributeName, attribute in classDict.items():
            if callable(attribute) and attributeName == '_run':
                newClassDict['run'] = wrapper(attribute)
            newClassDict[attributeName] = attribute
        print(classDict, newClassDict)
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, newClassDict)


class AmazingClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State.Idle

    def _run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.state)  # State.Running
        do_something()
        # After returning: self.state == State.Finished


class EvenMoreAmazingClass(AmazingClass):
    def _run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.state)  # State.Running
        super()._run(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.state)  # State.Running -> this is what you want
        do_something('else')


ddd = EvenMoreAmazingClass()
ddd.run()
print(ddd.state)  # Finished
```

Comment: While I really like your solution, I don't find it very intuitive to use.
e.g. a developer has to override _run() and call run(). The developer might make a typo/mistake and call/override run() instead of ._run() which would be fatal.  
Overall a great solution, I'll investigate a bit further and post an update.
Thanks already ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you'll never have anything other than the `run` method wrapped with `wrapper` you can implement a `StateHandler` class to handle the inner calls.

```
from functools import wraps
from types import FunctionType

class State:
    Running = 'State.Running'
    Finished = 'State.Finished'
    Idle = 'State.Idle'

class StateHandler:
    state = 0

    @staticmethod
    def incr():
        StateHandler.state += 1
        # always return State.running when calling StateHandler.incr()
        return State.Running 

    @staticmethod
    def decr():
        StateHandler.state -= 1
        # only return State.Finished when the outer 
        # method has completed. 
        if StateHandler.state:
            return State.Running
        return State.Finished

def wrapper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.state = StateHandler.incr()
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.state = StateHandler.decr()
    return wrapped

class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, class_name, bases, dct):
        new_dct = {}
        for name, attribute in dct.items():
            if isinstance(attribute, FunctionType) and name == 'run':
                attribute = wrapper(attribute)
            new_dct[name] = attribute
        return type.__new__(meta, class_name, bases, new_dct)


class AmazingClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = State.Idle

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.state)  # State.Running


class EvenMoreAmazingClass(AmazingClass):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.state)  # State.Running
        super().run(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.state)


foo = EvenMoreAmazingClass()
print(foo.state)
foo.run()
print(foo.state)
```

I added a toy `State` implementation to make the example runnable.

This works by incrementing `StateHandler.state` every time a `run` method is called and decrementing when it ends. So `StateHandler.state` is `1` at the outer call, `2` at the inner call, `1` at the inner `return` and `0` at the outer `return`.

This effectively causes `State.Finished` to be set ONLY when the initial `run` method that was called has returned. So it works for both your base class and derived class implementations.