# Is there a way to trace all methods called on an instance of a class, including dunder methods?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-class

I'm looking for a means to trace all calls on an instance of a class, including calls to dunder methods like `__iter__`, `__getattribute__` etc. I've tried using `sys.setprofile`, the `autologging` package, but failed : it doesn't seem to be able to trace calls to dundermethods, or attributes etc.

My usecase is the following. Python's duck typing is awesome, and I would need to be able to "mock" objects, implementing a class only with the necessary methods (including magic or dunders). As I understand duck typing (tell me if i'm misleading), it's basically the fact that the following code will work for **any** object `instance_of_class` as long as it implements the methods necessary for iterables (`__iter__` and `__next__` for example) and that elements returned implements `object.__getattribute__('name')` which result has `__repr__` method, for the printing

```
import ExternalClass

ExternalClass = my_awesome_decorator_to_trace_them_all(ExternalClass)
instance_of_class = ExternalClass(...)
for element in instance_of_class:
    print(element.name)
```

So, I would like to be able to trace variables (or the original class, and then every instances will get traced), using for example a decorator or anything, that would show the list of all methods called. In the previous example for `ExternalClass`, it would be:

```
method __init__ called with arguments ...
method __new__ called with arguments ...
method __iter__ called with arguments ...
method __next__ called with arguments ...
```

Thanks for the help

--- Update with @martineau efficient and elegant solution

From @martineau's [working code](https://pastebin.com/hPXvMNMN) on [How to wrap every method of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class)

```
from functools import wraps
from types import FunctionType


def wrapper(method):
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        class_name = args[0].__class__.__name__
        func_name = method.__name__
        print('calling {}.{}()... '.format(class_name, func_name))
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


class MetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        newClassDict = {}
        for attributeName, attribute in classDict.items():
            if isinstance(attribute, FunctionType):
                # replace it with a wrapped version
                attribute = wrapper(attribute)
            newClassDict[attributeName] = attribute
        return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, newClassDict)

class SimpleList(object, metaclass=MetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_elem = list(range(1))

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        this_index = self.index
        if this_index >= len(self.list_elem):
            raise StopIteration()
        self.index += 1
        return self.list_elem[this_index]


simple_list = SimpleList()
print(simple_list)
for element in simple_list:
    pass
```

prints the following

```
calling SimpleList.__init__()...
<__main__.SimpleList object at 0x1054ce9a0>
calling SimpleList.__iter__()...
calling SimpleList.__next__()...
calling SimpleList.__next__()...
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I mentioned I tried settrace, but after your answer, I doublechecked and it works but does not follow a particular object or class : it prints all calls. It definitely is a good one though, I'll try modifying it and edit my question with the results ! thanks

Comment: See [How to wrap every method of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349183/how-to-wrap-every-method-of-a-class)

Comment: so efficient and elegant solution, thanks! I didn't know about metaclasses. Editing the question right away

Comment: Nice to hear — and you're welcome — but Michael Foord should get most of the credit since my code was based on what's in the [his blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200124090402id_/http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/metaclasses.shtml#a-method-decorating-metaclass).

Comment: Also note that you can up-vote my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350487/355230) to the linked question if you found it helpful.

Comment: will do! thanks for Michael Foord's blog, I did look for it but couldn't find

Comment: Thanks. There are links to the relevant portions of a blog entry of his titled [Meta-classes Made Easy](https://web.archive.org/web/20200124090402id_/http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/metaclasses.shtml) in my previous comment and my linked answer, so you don't have to look for them. I think his blog is now discontinued.