Wait in a method until some methods finished in another threads
I need to implement the waiting in a method until some other methods in different threads are finished.
This is my implementation (not working as expected):
import queue
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
import time
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(message)s",
)


class Foo(object):

    def func_1(self):
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.info("start func_1")
        time.sleep(2)
        log.info("end func_1")

    def func_2(self):
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.info("start func_2")
        time.sleep(2)
        log.info("end func_2")

    def func_3(self):
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.info("start func_3")
        time.sleep(2)
        log.info("end func_3")

    def func_4_free(self):
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.info("start func_4_free")
        time.sleep(2)
        log.info("end func_4_free")

    def do(self):
        log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        log.info("start do")
        time.sleep(1)
        log.info("This is do")
        time.sleep(1)
        log.info("end do")

class Bar(Foo):

    cv_from_do = threading.Event()

    FUNC_SYNCHRONISE = {"do": ["func_1", "func_2", "func_3", "do"]}

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.funcs = queue.Queue()
        self.cv_from_do.set()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attribute = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name in ["cv_from_do", "funcs", "FUNC_SYNCHRONISE"]:
            return attribute
        if name in self.FUNC_SYNCHRONISE.keys():
            def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
                log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                log.info(f"start {name}. wait till other functions finish...")
                try:
                    self.cv_from_do.wait()
                    self.cv_from_do.clear()  # force to wait other functions
                    while not self.funcs.empty():
                        pass
                    self.funcs.put(name)
                    attribute(*args, **kwargs)
                    self.funcs.get(name)
                    self.cv_from_do.set()
                except Exception as ex:
                    log.exception(ex)
            return wrap
        elif name in self.FUNC_SYNCHRONISE["do"]:
            def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
                log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                try:
                    self.cv_from_do.wait()
                    self.funcs.put(name)
                    attribute(*args, **kwargs)
                    self.funcs.get(name)
                except Exception as ex:
                    log.exception(ex)
            return wrap
        else:
            return attribute


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
    obj = Bar()
    # function of 'obj' can be called any times, in any threads, in any order
    # following is just for test
    for f in [obj.func_1, obj.func_3, obj.func_4_free, obj.do, obj.func_2, obj.func_1, obj.do, obj.func_4_free, obj.do, obj.func_3, obj.func_2, obj.func_1]:
        future = executor.submit(
            f,
            **{}
        )


The inheritance must be preserved Bar(Foo). Foo - must not be modified
The expectation is:

Function of obj = Bar() can be called in a thread in any amount, in any time.
When any functions are started in threads they are working
independent in parallel.
Once do starts in a thread - it waits until other functions (including other dos if they exist in other threads) finish, then other functions wait until the current do is finished. Once current do finishes -> other functions can continue.
Only function of Foo in FUNC_SYNCHRONISE have to be synchronized. Other functions of Foo can work independently.

I got following output:
start func_1
start func_3
start func_4_free
start do. wait till other functions finish...
start do. wait till other functions finish...
start func_4_free
start do. wait till other functions finish...
end func_1
end func_3
end func_4_free
start do              <<< - from here
end func_4_free
This is do
end do                <<< - to here is correct. 'do' behaves atomic
start do              <<< - from here
start func_1          <<< - to here is NOT correct, as 'do' has to be finished before other methods sart
start func_3
start func_2
start func_2
start func_1
This is do
end func_1
end do
end func_3
end func_2
end func_2
end func_1
start do
This is do
end do

The problem is that if there is only one do in threads - no problem, my code is working. But if I call several do in different threads - the first is working as expected, but next dos are called without waiting for completion of each other. In short - do should be called in sequential mode, never in concurrent to each other.
Please help if possible..
UPD
I'm thinking to create a queue of do and allow them to execute when it is its time.. but it is not an atomic (as I need to check the element in queue and only after pop it) and may lead to concurrency problems i believe

You can simplify matters by using a read-write lock:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import logging

from rwlock import RWLock # e.g. https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/a7ff6017b7a1f9a506cf75aa23eacfd6
from so79082898 import Foo

class Bar(Foo):
    FUNC_SYNCHRONISE = {"do": ["func_1", "func_2", "func_3", "do"]}

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._lock = RWLock()

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attribute = super().__getattribute__(name)
        if name in ["_lock", "FUNC_SYNCHRONISE"]:
            return attribute
        if name in self.FUNC_SYNCHRONISE.keys():
            def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
                log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
                log.info(f"start {name}. wait till other functions finish...")
                with self._lock.w_locked():
                    attribute(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrap
        elif name in self.FUNC_SYNCHRONISE["do"]:
            def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
                with self._lock.r_locked():
                    attribute(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrap
        else:
            return attribute


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
        obj = Bar()
        # function of 'obj' can be called any times, in any threads, in any order
        # following is just for test
        for f in [obj.func_1, obj.func_3, obj.func_4_free, obj.do, obj.func_2, obj.func_1, obj.do, obj.func_4_free, obj.do, obj.func_3, obj.func_2, obj.func_1]:
            future = executor.submit(
                f,
                **{}
            )


there are keys and values in FUNC_SYNCHRONISE which implies you might want to synchronise different sets of functions independently, but neither the original or this implementation does that. But having that dict makes it a bit more complicated that it could be.
this uses a per-instance lock rather than per-class, not sure if that matters
probably could be improved by wrapping the functions only once on construction, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11350487
switching to reentrant locks might be needed if some methods call other methods, and using a R/W lock library than allows promotion of read to write could simplify the code (as all methods then can get a read lock and only 'do' can then promote to write) and may be needed if you have more than one set of key/value pairs in FUNC_SYNCRONISE

